# IE 9 and Fullpage.js Normal Scroll Elements

Tags: fullpage.js

So I'm using fullpage.js by alvarotrigo. I just want to ask if `normalScrollElements` function of this plugin has issues on IE. Because on Chrome, Firefox and Safari the `normalScrollElements` is working fine. However on **IE 9** it is not. Any thoughts on this one? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[It was already reported](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/634) in the plugin forum.

The problem was solved in version 2.1.9 of fullpage.js